# Extract String Resource Pop-up in Android Studio Not Showing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

While adding the android:text="" property to my XML file, I want to quickly extract the string, but the quickfix option is not showing up anymore

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iAAW.png

Here's a picture of what shows up when I use ALT+ENTER in the string. I also want to mention that it used to work no problem before, but suddenly it just doesn't appear anymore. I checked the option in the File/Settings/Editor/Intentions/Android/Extract string resource as well and it still didn't solve the problem.

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: Can you please add layout code here?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using old compileSdk version.(33 to 31 for me)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

By modifying as below, it works. In `build.gradle`,

1. Change the version of `compileSdk` and `targetSdk` from `33` to `31`
2. Downgrade the versions as following.

`androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0`
`androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1`
`com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0`